# i try to get the group (manytomany) of user but throws me int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I use the model by default: `User` and `Group`, in my model if I use

```
a = request.user.groups.all
```

in my template appears:

```
[<Group: jefes>]
```

but I only need "jefes" and not `[<Group: jefes>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `all` method return a `ManyRelatedManager` which is basically a list in python. If you want to get the group and not the whole list you may do:

```
a = request.user.groups.all()[0]
print a
>>> <Group: jefes>
```

Watch it that this way you access the first element in the list. If the list doesn't contains any elements this will yield `Index out of bounds` exception.

Hope this helps!

Comment: now shows me error when the user has no groups. but perfect, very thanks for your help and explication.

Comment: thanks! Paulo, I am learning Django since 2 month ago, and I love it